# Filter out comments with specific words that are found in a Laravel collection

Tags: php, laravel, collections, filtering

I am trying to filter out comments that have specific words in them. I am displaying random positive comments. I don't want them to contain words like too, small, please, next. And where the comments are a minimum of 3 words.

Each notes and commentsRating is a database field

I have the code that grabs me a random comment from the $commentsGood array. I want to make sure they don't contain those words mentioned above. Also if someone knows how to stream line the current array I have, would love to learn something new thanks.

EDIT to show were the data is grabbed and what it returns.

```
$commentsRatings = Rating::all();

                $commentsGood = collect([
                $comments1 = $commentsRatings->where('commentsRating_1', '=', 5)->where('notes_1', '!=', '')->pluck('notes_1', 'feedback_user_id')->all(),
                $comments2 = $commentsRatings->where('commentsRating_2', '=', 5)->where('notes_1', '!=', '')->pluck('notes_2', 'feedback_user_id')->all(),
                $comments3 = $commentsRatings->where('commentsRating_3', '=', 5)->where('notes_1', '!=', '')->pluck('notes_3', 'feedback_user_id')->all(),
                $comments3 = $commentsRatings->where('commentsRating_4', '=', 5)->where('notes_1', '!=', '')->pluck('notes_4', 'feedback_user_id')->all(),
                $comments5 = $commentsRatings->where('commentsRating_5', '=', 5)->where('notes_1', '!=', '')->pluck('notes_5', 'feedback_user_id')->all(),
                $comments6 = $commentsRatings->where('commentsRating_6', '=', 5)->where('notes_1', '!=', '')->pluck('notes_6', 'feedback_user_id')->all(),
                $comments7 = $commentsRatings->where('commentsRating_7', '=', 5)->where('notes_1', '!=', '')->pluck('notes_7', 'feedback_user_id')->all(),
                $comments8 = $commentsRatings->where('commentsRating_8', '=', 5)->where('notes_1', '!=', '')->pluck('notes_8', 'feedback_user_id')->all()
              ]);

dd($commentsGood);
```

returns

```
Collection {#332 ▼
   #items: array:8 [▼
0 => array:279 [▶]
1 => array:205 [▶]
2 => array:194 [▶]
3 => array:115 [▶]
4 => array:46 [▶]
5 => array:29 [▶]
6 => array:13 [▶]
7 => array:4 [▼
  0 => "Can you please provide some answers"
  1 => "Perfect!"
  2 => "This is just too much to read"
  3 => "a little tight in the shoulders  "
]]}
```

Out of this array of arrays I want to remove any full comments that include the words like the ones mentioned above.

I then run shuffle->take(1)->first to get something like. to only get one of the arrays to then get a random line from there. 
the array returns sentences not single words, for example

```
array:29 [▼
  0 => "I typically would not have worn something like this but just 
  loved it. "
  1 => "please take this comment"
  2 => "Cool jeans, but one size too large."
```

Comment: show what `dd($commentsGood)` gives

Comment: It is just an array of comments. Keys are numbers and the values are the comments. so it would be something like: array:29 [▼
  0 => "some comment"
  1 => "some other comment with the word please in it"
  2 => "and so on"
...

Comment: `filter` your collection, then pick one randomly

Comment: Ther3 i$ a perfec11y g00d rea$on nobody doe$ this anymore. Don't do it either.

Comment: @Sohel0415 I'm trying to see what that filter looks like. As I want to filter out the words but I get the expects string and array given error.

Comment: 1t d0e$n't work

Answer (score 1):

> I have the code that grabs me a random comment from the `$commentsGood` array. I want to make sure they don't contain those words mentioned above.

Since you're already getting the string randomly from this collection and you just want to check it, use Laravel's [`str_contains()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-str-contains) (not PHP's native `str_contains()`) with an array as the second parameter:

```
if (str_contains($text, ['too', 'small', 'please', 'next']))
```

Comment: Can this be used as a ->where added to the query instead of an if?

Comment: You can use `filter()` collection method with a closure where you could use `str_contains()`

Comment: can you show me that with using a filter? Much appreciated

Comment: @vvp24 you can find a simple example in [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-filter) which can help you to understand how it works. I can't provide you the exact code because you didn't show how do you get the data for the collection and what's its structure.

Comment: Hope with the edit you can give me a better example. I did review the documentation before jumping on this. I and tried the other answers provided I usually get the following error: mb_strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you.

If you have $commentsGood as an array of needed words, then (just update this method to use your columns and models):

```
$disabledWords = ['too', 'small', 'please', 'next'];

$comments = Model::where(function ($q) use ($disabledWords) {
    foreach ($disabledWords as $value) {
        $q->orWhere('comment', 'not like', "%{$value}%");
    }
})->get();
```

You can try `like` or `not like`

---

With your example:

```
$disabledWords = ['too', 'small', 'please', 'next'];

$comments1 = $commentsRatings->where('commentsRating_1', '=', 5)
    ->where('notes_1', '!=', '')
    ->pluck('notes_1', 'feedback_user_id')
    ->where(function ($q) use ($disabledWords) {
        foreach ($disabledWords as $value) {
            $q->orWhere('comment', 'not like', "%{$value}%");
        }
    })
    ->get();
```

And please, create a function to be more simple and clean ;)
For example:

```
public function getComments($commentsType, $notesType)
{
    $disabledWords = ['too', 'small', 'please', 'next'];
    return $this
        ->where($commentsType, '=', 5)
        ->where('notes_1', '!=', '')
        ->pluck($notesType, 'feedback_user_id')
        ->where(function ($q) use ($disabledWords) {
            foreach ($disabledWords as $value) {
                $q->orWhere('comment', 'not like', "%{$value}%");
            }
        })
        ->get();
}
```

And then use:

```
$commentsGood = collect([
    $commentsRatings->getComments('commentsRating_1', 'notes_1'),
    $commentsRatings->getComments('commentsRating_2', 'notes_2'),
    $commentsRatings->getComments('commentsRating_3', 'notes_3'),
    $commentsRatings->getComments('commentsRating_4', 'notes_4'),
    $commentsRatings->getComments('commentsRating_5', 'notes_5'),
    $commentsRatings->getComments('commentsRating_6', 'notes_6'),
    $commentsRatings->getComments('commentsRating_7', 'notes_7'),
    $commentsRatings->getComments('commentsRating_8', 'notes_8'),
]);
```

Comment: for this query can it be built into the array query?   $comments1 = $commentsRatings->where('commentsRating_1', '=', 5)->where('notes_1', '!=', '')->pluck('notes_1', 'feedback_user_id')->all(),

Comment: Add this `where` statement from my answer into your $comments1... and this will work, and use `get` not `all`

    $comments1 = $commentsRatings->where('commentsRating_1', '=', 5)->where('notes_1', '!=', '')->pluck('notes_1', 'feedback_user_id')->where(function ($q) use ($disabledWords) {
    foreach ($disabledWords as $value) {
        $q->orWhere('comment', 'not like', "%{$value}%");
    }
})->get();

Comment: Thanks for helping out Mateusz I really appreciate helping me code better and learning new things. Where do you get $commentType and $notesType from? Is that just referring to all comments instead of referring to them individually?

Answer (score 0):

Use `map()` collection method to map your collection, `array_filter()` to filter your array and Laravel's `str_contains()` (not PHP's `str_contains()`) to check:

```
$commentsGood = $commentsGood->map(function($item){
        return array_filter($item, function($i){
            return !str_contains($i, ['too', 'small', 'please', 'next']);
        });
})->values();
```

then randomly pick `one`.

Comment: I'm getting the following error. mb_strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: @vvp24 I have updated my answer according to your data, it should work now.